# Flink running on Docker Swarm can't resolve jobmanager if machines are in different virtual network/subnet

Tags: azure, docker, google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, docker-swarm

I am running the standard Flink Docker project from:
https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink

The machines which are part of the swarm are in different clouds: Azure and Google Cloud.

Here are the steps to reproduce.

1. Create swarm: `docker swarm init --advertise-addr XXXXXX`
2. Create registry: `docker service create --name registry --publish 5000:5000 registry:2`
3. Add all machines to the swarm using the worker token from above.

   `docker node ls` shows all machines as "Ready".
4. Push image to registry: `docker-compose push`
5. Deploy Flink service to swarm: `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml flink`
6. Scale Flink service: `docker service scale flink_taskmanager=20`
7. Keep checking `docker service ps flink_taskmanager | grep Running`

Docker swarm will attempt to start flink_taskmanager in all machines, but the ones which are not in the same virtual network/subnet as the container running flink_jobmanager will fail with the error below:

```
2017-10-31 22:37:32,255 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation               - PriviledgedActionException as:flink (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.net.UnknownHostException: jobmanager: Name or service not known
2017-10-31 22:37:32,256 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Failed to run TaskManager.
java.net.UnknownHostException: jobmanager: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:138)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.selectNetworkInterfaceAndRunTaskManager(TaskManager.scala:1663)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anon$2.call(TaskManager.scala:1574)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anon$2.call(TaskManager.scala:1572)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.main(TaskManager.scala:1572)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.main(TaskManager.scala)
```

---

This is a few seconds after I scale up the Task Manager (before they fail):

```
thalita@ubuntu-swarm-manager:~/flink/flink-contrib/docker-flink$ docker service ps flink_taskmanager | grep Running
ktcy4ujro1yo  flink_taskmanager.1       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 4 seconds ago
qbpjoua6ctbg  flink_taskmanager.2       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 12 seconds ago
ymlripufi9qe  flink_taskmanager.3       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 16 seconds ago
xvfcqj2cnnph  flink_taskmanager.4       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 15 seconds ago
lwvkkz3mx7ij  flink_taskmanager.6       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 7 seconds ago
wrb78346dvmg  flink_taskmanager.7       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  google-cloud-worker-1  Running        Running 5 seconds ago
m31bf1cenevj  flink_taskmanager.8       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  google-cloud-worker-1  Running        Running 5 seconds ago
oe2ff8ijuer4  flink_taskmanager.9       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 11 seconds ago
vuw3dxugyjyi  flink_taskmanager.10      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 15 seconds ago
xhmdbi9jad86  flink_taskmanager.11      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 10 seconds ago
o3tw38bok4b9  flink_taskmanager.12      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 10 minutes ago
knc54g7ayp1g  flink_taskmanager.13      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  google-cloud-worker-1  Running        Running 7 seconds ago
bqio2ubvik5j  flink_taskmanager.14      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 6 seconds ago
qauubxm3msda  flink_taskmanager.15      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  google-cloud-worker-1  Running        Running 5 seconds ago
v9hjfadfn9y6  flink_taskmanager.16      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 4 seconds ago
d8oh7ol4g90y  flink_taskmanager.17      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  google-cloud-worker-1  Running        Running 3 seconds ago
9d4m7bb1bprp  flink_taskmanager.18      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 10 seconds ago
ri00r8ehvwsh  flink_taskmanager.19      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 5 seconds ago
```

---

A few seconds later, only the Azure ones are running:

```
docker service ps flink_taskmanager | grep Running
ktcy4ujro1yo  flink_taskmanager.1       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
qbpjoua6ctbg  flink_taskmanager.2       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
ymlripufi9qe  flink_taskmanager.3       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
xvfcqj2cnnph  flink_taskmanager.4       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
5efusat5ay60  flink_taskmanager.5       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
lwvkkz3mx7ij  flink_taskmanager.6       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
v2vndema8k74  flink_taskmanager.7       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
l92tjj0498v2  flink_taskmanager.8       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
oe2ff8ijuer4  flink_taskmanager.9       flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
vuw3dxugyjyi  flink_taskmanager.10      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
xhmdbi9jad86  flink_taskmanager.11      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
o3tw38bok4b9  flink_taskmanager.12      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 12 minutes ago
6rlm2pu2gn21  flink_taskmanager.13      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
bqio2ubvik5j  flink_taskmanager.14      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
63r9kmrh46gw  flink_taskmanager.15      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
v9hjfadfn9y6  flink_taskmanager.16      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
vmrf20o9eo5m  flink_taskmanager.17      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
9d4m7bb1bprp  flink_taskmanager.18      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
ri00r8ehvwsh  flink_taskmanager.19      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
8h21y4r49scb  flink_taskmanager.20      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-2   Running        Running 2 minutes ago
```

---

Which is where the Job Manager is also running:

```
docker service ps flink_jobmanager | grep Running
p6bzg567ewhn  flink_jobmanager.1      flink:1.3.2-hadoop2-scala_2.10  azure-swarm-worker-1  Running        Running about an hour ago
```

---

This is the docker logs when I use the create-docker-swarm-service.sh script from https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink to create the service:

```
Starting Task Manager
config file:
jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
parallelism.default: 1
jobmanager.web.port: 8081
blob.server.port: 6124
query.server.port: 6125
Starting taskmanager as a console application on host c42a6093f7bb.
2017-11-01 11:20:51,459 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Starting TaskManager (Version: 1.3.2, Rev:0399bee, Date:03.08.2017 @ 10:23:11 UTC)
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Current user: flink
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.141-b15
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Maximum heap size: 1024 MiBytes
2017-11-01 11:20:51,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JAVA_HOME: /docker-java-home/jre
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Hadoop version: 2.7.2
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM Options:
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:+UseG1GC
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xms1024M
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xmx1024M
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/opt/flink/conf/logback-console.xml
2017-11-01 11:20:51,526 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Program Arguments:
2017-11-01 11:20:51,527 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     --configDir
2017-11-01 11:20:51,527 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     /opt/flink/conf
2017-11-01 11:20:51,527 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Classpath: /opt/flink/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.3.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/flink/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.3.2.jar:::
2017-11-01 11:20:51,527 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-01 11:20:51,528 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-11-01 11:20:51,532 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Maximum number of open file descriptors is 1048576
2017-11-01 11:20:51,548 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Loading configuration from /opt/flink/conf
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, flink-jobmanager
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 2
2017-11-01 11:20:51,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-11-01 11:20:51,552 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2017-11-01 11:20:51,552 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-11-01 11:20:51,552 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: blob.server.port, 6124
2017-11-01 11:20:51,553 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: query.server.port, 6125
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, flink-jobmanager
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 2
2017-11-01 11:20:51,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-11-01 11:20:51,561 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2017-11-01 11:20:51,561 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-11-01 11:20:51,561 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: blob.server.port, 6124
2017-11-01 11:20:51,561 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: query.server.port, 6125
2017-11-01 11:20:51,585 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to flink (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-11-01 11:20:51,621 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Failed to run TaskManager.
java.net.UnknownHostException: flink-jobmanager: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:138)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.selectNetworkInterfaceAndRunTaskManager(TaskManager.scala:1663)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anon$2.call(TaskManager.scala:1574)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anon$2.call(TaskManager.scala:1572)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.main(TaskManager.scala:1572)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.main(TaskManager.scala)
```

Comment: I suspect this might be a Flink configuration issue. The same thing happens when I create the Swarm service using the create-docker-swarm-service script in:  https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink